# Is there anyway to find all tests that are disabled in a TestNG suite?

Tags: java, testing, automation, testng

In TestNG, you disable tests by doing the following in the method:

```
@Test(enabled = false)
```

I was wondering if there was an automated way to scrub the entire suite in order to find all of the methods that have enabled set to false?

Comment: You can do a search within your project for that specific string, `@Test(enabled = false)`.  That will show you each instance where that is used.

Comment: How would I do that in the IDE? (I'm using Eclipse)

Comment: CTRL + ALT + G.

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: Yes @Brian, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [`IAnnotationTransformer`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers):

```
public class MyTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

  public void transform(ITest annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    if (!annotation.getEnabled()) {
      System.out.println(testClass != null ? testClass : testMethod);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look at your entire code without using the transformer, you may try my [dedicated library](https://github.com/AutomatedOwl/testng-disabled-tests):

```
@Listeners(DisabledTestsListener.class)
public class InventoryTests {

    @Test
    @DisabledTestsCollector(testsPath = "/src/test/java")
    void getDisabledTest() {
        // This test would collect all disabled tests in TestNG project.
    }
```

Output example:

```
Jul 14, 2018 11:57:28 AM com.github.automatedowl.tools.DisabledTestsListener afterInvocation
INFO: You have 2 disabled TestNG tests in your project.
Jul 14, 2018 11:57:28 AM com.github.automatedowl.tools.DisabledTestsListener afterInvocation
INFO: ---------------------------------------------
Jul 14, 2018 11:57:28 AM com.github.automatedowl.tools.DisabledTestsListener lambda$afterInvocation$0
INFO:  firstDisabledTest is a TestNG test which currently disabled.
Jul 14, 2018 11:57:28 AM com.github.automatedowl.tools.DisabledTestsListener lambda$afterInvocation$0
INFO: ---------------------------------------------
Jul 14, 2018 11:57:28 AM com.github.automatedowl.tools.DisabledTestsListener lambda$afterInvocation$0
INFO:  secondDisabledTest is a TestNG test which currently disabled.
Jul 14, 2018 11:57:28 AM com.github.automatedowl.tools.DisabledTestsListener lambda$afterInvocation$0
INFO: ---------------------------------------------
```